# Instantiate a Java Generic class in a generic class

Tags: java, generics

Here is a minimal code example. The interface:

```
interface Individual<T>  {
    public T getVariableValue(int index) ;
    public void setVariableValue(int index, T value) ;

    public int getNumberOfVariables() ;
    public int getNumberOfObjectives() ;

    public Individual<T> copy() ;
}
```

And the class:

```
public class  minimalExample<S extends Individual> {

    private List<S> doCrossover(List<S> s){
        S mom = s.get(0);
        S dad = s.get(1);

        int crossoverPoint = 5;

        S girl = mom.copy();
        S boy = dad.copy();
        for (int i = 0; i < mom.getNumberOfVariables(); i++) {
            if(i > crossoverPoint){
                boy.setVariableValue(i, mom.getVariableValue(i));
                girl.setVariableValue(i,dad.getVariableValue(i));
            }
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

If i try to compile this i get:

```
java: incompatible types: Individual cannot be converted to S
```

Which seems confusing. Doesn' the `extends` keyword mean that S has to be of type Individual or a subtype?

Comment: your copy method has a returntype T not S. i wonder you do not have to cast it to S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which seems confusing. Doesn' the `extends` keyword mean that S has to be of type Individual or a subtype?

Yes, but that does not mean that the type returned by an `S`'s `copy()` method is also an `S`.  The `Individual` interface requires only that it be an `Individual`.

Moreover, I observe that your class `minimalExample` is using the raw type `Individual`, whereas it ought to use a properly parameterized version (or else `Individual` should be made non-generic).

You may be over-parameterizing here.  Does `minimalExample` really need to use `S` instead of directly using `Individual`?  Obviously, this example class does not, but perhaps the one that inspired the question doesn't, either.

On the other hand, if you *do* need a parameter for the specific type of `Individual`, then perhaps you need to *further* parameterize that interface to describe the kind of object its `copy()` method returns:

```
interface Individual<T,I extends Individual<T, I>>  {
    public T getVariableValue(int index) ;
    public void setVariableValue(int index, T value) ;

    public int getNumberOfVariables() ;
    public int getNumberOfObjectives() ;

    public I copy() ;
}
```

You could then declare your class `MinimalExample` with the needed additional information:

```
public class MinimalExample<T, S extends Individual<T, S>> {
    // ...
}
```

And here is a dummy implementation of `Individual` that you could use with that:

```
public class ExampleIndividual<T> implements Individual<T, ExampleIndividual<T>> {

    public T getVariableValue(int index) { return null; }
    public void setVariableValue(int index, T value) {}

    public int getNumberOfVariables() { return 0; }
    public int getNumberOfObjectives() { return 0; }

    public ExampleIndividual<T> copy() { return new ExampleIndividual<T>(); }

}
```

Comment: You were right. I was over-parametizing. The final solution in the example would be to just use a generic <S> and then use Individual<S> all other places.

Answer (score 1):

The method copy() returns an object of type "Individual", which cannot be assigned to the type "S" since S is a subtype.

Why are girl and boy declared to be of type "S" and not Individual?